Get bytes from MagickImage image
Is there a straight forward way to get the bytes from a MagickImage?
That is, like writing it to a file but, instead, writing it to a byte array.

Write it to a memory stream and then convert to array
var img = new MagickImage();
// or however you get your image in first place
using var ms = new MemoryStream();
img.Write(ms, img.Format);
var bytes = ms.ToArray();

Depending on size and what you are doing with image, keeping stream and writing to asynchronously would probably be preferrable to loading entire image into memory in one go but guessing by your reputation you know that already.
